# Multi language basic php website without subdomain or sub-folders

Tags: .htaccess, seo, multilingual

Right now I have a website which uses two languages English and German. There is no sub folders or sub-domains used. Correct language is shown using a `$_Session[lang]`, and gettext function.

```
example.com/about-us.php
```

If the `'$_Session[lang]' = en` then the page shown in English
and if `'$_Session[lang]' = de` then the page shown in Dutch

But its not SEO freindly. I want to keep the structure of the folders same and want to add a paramenter in url to specify the language. like

```
example.com/en/about-us.php
```

for English and

```
example.com/de/about-us.php
```

for German.

"both pages example.com/en/about-us.php and example.com/de/about-us.php
should point to file root/webspace/about-us.php, that is, folders /en and /de are VIRTUAL (should not exist in reality to avoid code redundance). Inside file about-us.php we should be able to know which virtual folder was called (/en or /de) to be able to define the session variable that will define GETTEXT's language.

How can I accomplish this? 
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Where does the `$_Session` array come from? Also, typically "**de**" is [ISO-639 for "German"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), **"nl"** is for "Dutch"

Comment: Thanks Jon for your reply. $_SESSION is set default to English, and on an image click(flag), it can be set to German. Thas way its working now, but not SEO freindly, I have expanded my question a littlebit. "both pages example.com/en/about-us.php and example.com/de/about-us.php
should point to file root/webspace/about-us.php, that is, folders /en and /de are VIRTUAL (should not exist in reality to avoid code redundance). Inside file about-us.php we should be able to know which virtual folder was called (/en or /de) to be able to define the session variable that will define GETTEXT's language."